# Trouble with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when using OkHttp 4.9.3

Tags: java, maven, okhttp

I'm encountering a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` issue while using OkHttp version 4.9.3 in my Java Maven project. The error is related to the `RequestBody.create` method. I've double-checked my code and dependencies, but I'm still unable to resolve this issue.

```
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(json, MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"));

request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(urlBuilder.build())
                    .headers(headersBuilder.build())
                    .post(requestBody)
                    .build();
```

In my pom.xml file,

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
   <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
   <version>4.9.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm receiving the following error message,

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'okhttp3.RequestBody
> okhttp3.RequestBody.create(java.lang.String, okhttp3.MediaType)'

I'm unsure why I'm still encountering this error despite using a version of OkHttp that should support the RequestBody.create method. Are there any additional troubleshooting steps I could take to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please put your `pom` in the question.

Comment: you need to provide more information. for now, it looks like something is missing at the classpath. Which build tool are you using? And do you really have `okhttp:4.9.3` added to classpath?

Comment: @catch23 I am using Maven and I updated the question with how I add it a s dependency.

Comment: It is a IDE problem i guess. Are you using eclipse?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ Idea, but actually, this is thrown from the docker container.

Comment: @AbrahamArnold I tried to reproduce it locally and it worked fine with `okhttp` version at IntelliJ IDE.

Comment: Actually, I saw what's happening, I am using this project as a Java Library, and even though I use 4.9.3 as the version here, In the main project it shows as 3.14., So I added version 4.9.3 to the main project and it worked fine. I still don't understand why is that.